# How can I take an arbitrary input as a variable in clingo(Answer set programming)?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

For example, I input four node:

```
node(a). node(b). node(c). node(d).
```

Without no hard-code, how can I pick an arbitrary input as a variable.

I set a root(A)

I want root(A) equal to node(a)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the clause `root(A):- node(A).`, then you will also get `root(a)`, ..., `root(d)` in the answer set.

Answer (score 0):

Something like
`root(X) :- X=#min{V : node(V)}.`

should do the trick. This takes the lexicographically smallest one (which is kind of arbitrary ;) ).